# Highcharts tick height in navigator

Tags: highcharts, height

I want to change the height tick in navigator. Is it possible?
Thanks!

[img example](http://wdda.pro/docs/obmen/123123.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tickLength](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickLength) parameter.

```
 xAxis: {
        tickLength: 20
 },
```

Comment: Omg! It works. I was looking for tickHeight. Thank you) I thought tickLength = number, sorry.